# VBA - Overflow error if passing certain digits to another sub

Tags: vba, byval

I've created a UserForm where I input a number or name, which will then look up some information based on this. If the input is numeric it calls the sub OpslagNummer and pass along the input from the UserForm. The problem is that it always gives me an "Overflow" error on certain number fx 61001 or 56001, where 10001 works just fine?

Code in UserFrom 1:

```
Sub TextBox1_KeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift 
As Integer)
If KeyCode = 13 Then
    UserForm1.Hide
    TextInput = TextBox1.Value
    UserForm1.TextBox1 = ""

    TextInput = 61001 '----Hardcoded number for the sake of debugging

    If IsNumeric(TextInput) = True Then
        Call OpslagNummer(TextInput)
    Else
        If Len(TextInput) >= 3 Then
            Call OpslagNavn(TextInput)
        Else
            End
        End If
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

Code in Module1:

```
Sub OpslagNummer(ByVal TextBoxNumber As Integer)
    'Code that looks up the information
End Sub
```

Comment: An integer cannot be larger than 32767.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get an overflow because you have surpassed the maximum Integer value (32,767). In order to handle larger range of arguments, use Long. You can convert your Module 1 like so:

```
Sub OpslagNummer(ByVal TextBoxNumber As Long)
    'Code that looks up the information
End Sub
```

Here's a reference to basic data types for VB (and VBA): [Visual Basic Data Types](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Visual_Basic/Data_Types)

Comment: That works perfectly! Thank you so much, didn't even consider, that this could have been a problem.